# Node.JS - S3 Timing Out With Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My node.js project converts text to an mp3, saves it to my file system, then uploads to s3. I want this function to run consecutive times on a loop until the queue is complete, but only the first file is uploading successfully. Subsequent file uploads return this error: `400 Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.`

Here is my code:

```
function uploadit () {
  console.log('uploading the verse')
  AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '...', secretAccessKey: '...' });

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'myverses',
    Key: book.replace(/ /g, "")+reference.replace(/ /g, "")+".mp3",
    Body: myvariable,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  },function (resp) {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log('Successfully uploaded the verse.');
    addanother();
      });}
```

**EDIT:**

The `addanother();` function checks to see if there are any more files to generate and upload. If so, the following code is executed:

```
function addverse() {
    connection.query('SELECT versetext, book, mp3, id, reference FROM myverses where mp3 = "empty" limit 1',
    function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(error);
    var scripture = results[0].versetext;
    var book = results[0].book;
    var reference = results[0].reference.replace(":", " verse ");
    console.log(scripture + " " +  book.replace("1", "first").replace("2", "second").replace("3", "third") + " " + reference);
    var myverse = scripture + " " +  book.replace("1", "first").replace("2", "second").replace("3", "third") + " " + reference;
    var link = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myverses/" + book.replace(/ /g, "")+reference.replace(/ /g, "")+".mp3"



function linkit(){
   connection.query('update myverses set mp3 = ? where mp3 = "empty" limit 1', [link],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      console.log(error)

    })

}

txtomp3.getMp3(myverse, function(err, binaryStream){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }


function writeit() {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("myverse.mp3");
  console.log('recording the verse')
  file.write(binaryStream);
  file.end();
}

function uploadit () {
  console.log('uploading the verse')
  AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '...', secretAccessKey: '...' });

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'myverses',
    Key: book.replace(/ /g, "")+reference.replace(/ /g, "")+".mp3",
    Body: myvalue,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  },function (resp) {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log('Successfully uploaded the verse.');
    addanother();
      });}

writeit();
var myvalue = fs.createReadStream("myverse.mp3");
setTimeout(uploadit, 3000)

  });
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the code for `addanother` look like?

Comment: @MitchLillie - See my edited post, above.

Comment: I'm not sure now, and I don't think adding a bunch of other code will help me answer. But there are some possible solutions here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/281

Comment: Try `s3.upload` instead of `putObject`, or alternately `new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v2'})`

Comment: @MitchLillie `s3.upload` did the trick. Thanks!